# Script to detect if a certain website is up?

Tags: networking, bash, scripts, internet

Can I create a script that detects if certain website is up and then perhaps execute something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is very vague and lacking in important details. You’ll have a much better chance of getting good answers if you [edit] it to add relevant information such as what exactly you mean by “open”?  Be sure to read [ask].

Comment: I agree the question isn't detailed but I didn't know how to be more specific about the idea of a certain page loading in my browser .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  If you run this script and `checksitestatus.sh` and use `http://google.com` it'll say `site is up`.  If you type `http://googlex.com` it'll say `site is down`.

You would have to install `lynx` to from the repository with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lynx
```

The script (checksitestatus.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
    echo 'Missing parameter - site to check... exiting.'
    exit 0
fi

site=$1    
siteisdown=$(lynx -dump $site 2>&1 | egrep 'Alert!: Unable to connect to remote host.')

if [[ "$siteisdown" ]]
then
    echo "Site is down"
    # any other code here
else
    echo "Site is up"
    # any other code here
fi
```

Comment: I just tried and no matter what site I write it says Site is up . Any clue why ?

Comment: @OmarHossamAhmed It's written to test http connections.  What is the parameter you gave it?  You can study the `lynx -dump` output and modify it to work in other cases.

Comment: oh yes that was the issue , thx.

Comment: There's a small typo: *it'll say site id down...*